# Solution for Inviscid Flow in a Moving Corner

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, boundary-conditions

I am considering the below situation (taken from page 26 of Fluid Mechanics by Landau and Lifshitz) where an inviscid fluid flows into a corner and is then turned back around.  The corner is the meeting point of the two black lines forming an angle via the intersection of two planes.

I need a similar situation, but one of the black boundary lines slides along the other one at the point of intersection at some constant velocity $V$, so effectively the corner slides forward into the flow.  Does someone know if the velocity field for the flow or something similar exists in the literature in this case, or if not, the easiest way to derive it?

[image]

Comment: Is the left boundary sliding to the right at a constant velocity?  If so, what do you think an observer moving to the right at this same velocity would observe?

Comment: I know how it works in terms of observers, but how does it work in terms of satisfying the boundary conditions?

Comment: So if you take the frame where the boundary is stationary, does the solution for the inviscid flow into the corner and back around exist anywhere in the literature?

Comment: The change in the boundary conditions is that the velocity at large x is now equal to the actual velocity minus the velocity of the observer and the wall is no longer sliding.

Comment: The solution for the inviscid flow into the corner and back around  has to exist in the literature.  You just need to do a little searching.  It is going to involve the use of complex variables.  So, maybe, in books on complex variable applications.

Answer (score 1):

The inviscid solution is independent of whether the walls slides or not. In viscous fluids, the flow near the corner is described by the well-known [Taylor scraping problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_scraping_flow).

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the problem is independent on the sliding of the wall.

If the fluid is inviscid, it supports no shear stress. Thus the "tangential" motion of the walls can't introduce no stress into the flow field